# Undoing a path drawn on UIImageView in Swift

Tags: swift

I made an erase-effect on `UIImageView` by drawing a path with blend mode set to `clear` using the code below. How can I undo a given path, meaning restoring the original image under that path?

```
    func erase(from fromPoint: CGPoint, to toPoint: CGPoint) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)
        image?.draw(in: self.bounds)

        defer {
            self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        }

        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.move(to: fromPoint)
        path.addLine(to: toPoint)

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        context.setShouldAntialias(true)
        context.setLineCap(.round)
        context.setLineWidth(40)
        context.setBlendMode(.clear)
        context.addPath(path)
        context.strokePath()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you creating a new `UIImage`, discarding what was there.

Two options:

1. Save a copy of your old image and restore it when you want to revert.
2. Alternatively, don’t alter the `image` at all, and instead just apply a `mask` to the `UIImageView`:

   ```
   extension UIImageView {
       func erase(from fromPoint: CGPoint, to toPoint: CGPoint) {
           let maskImage = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds).image { rendererContext in
               let context = rendererContext.cgContext

               context.fill(bounds)

               let path = CGMutablePath()
               path.move(to: fromPoint)
               path.addLine(to: toPoint)

               context.setShouldAntialias(true)
               context.setLineCap(.round)
               context.setLineWidth(40)
               context.setBlendMode(.clear)
               context.addPath(path)
               context.strokePath()
           }
           mask = UIImageView(image: maskImage)
       }
   }
   ```

   Then, when you want to reverse it, just remove the mask.